# Is it better to create seperate user accounts for each domain, or have all your domains under one account?

Tags: web, shared-hosting, organization

I've been trying to figure out how to best organize the dozen or so websites I have on a shared hosting service.

Lately I've been thinking that it's safer/easier to have separate accounts for each site that I have, but then I've lost some of the ability to share files, applications and what not. It seems nice to have a partitioning of sites, but Im curious as to what more experienced people would say is a better approach for this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security of separation depends how the Web server is setup. Different configurations will severely weaken the security of the system, however it is still useful to separate sites for cleanliness and security.

Answer (score 3):

You should always have separate accounts, it's better for system security.

A small guide on basic shared hosting security is here: http://webhostinggeeks.com/blog/2010/02/25/an-introduction-to-linux-web-hosting-%E2%80%93-linux-vs-windows-web-hosting/